# Error while updating feature information to geoserver using wfst OL3

Tags: openlayers, update, wfs-t

I am trying to update feature information of wfs feature to geoserver using WFST in ol3. I am getting the below error in the response

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
 <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>                               
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for pos: 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for null: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119"
 Parsing failed for pos: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for null: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119"
 Parsing failed for null: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119"
 For input string: "8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119"</ows:ExceptionText>
```

The request is

```
<Transaction xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
  <Update typeName="geowebmap_ws:tn_highways" xmlns:feature="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/geowebmap_ws">
    <Property>
      <Name>the_geom</Name>
      <Value>
        <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:3857"> 
          <pos>8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119 undefined
          </pos>
        </Point>
      </Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>CATEGORY</Name>
        <Value>Automotive update test</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Name>NAME</Name>
      <Value>Level crossing</Value>
    </Property>
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <FeatureId fid="tn_poi.308"/>
    </Filter>
  </Update>
</Transaction>
```

I know there seems to some undefined null value in the request for pos but the object which i am sending to request doesnt has null value in it
[image]

Where does this undefined value comes from below is my code

```
    var self.feat_att = $$hashKey: "object:722"
    geometry: Object
    coordinates: Array[2]
      0: 8682209.29541959
      1: 1159929.44262119
     length: 2
     type: "Point"
     geometry_name: "the_geom"
     id: "tn_poi.308"
     properties: Object
       CATEGORY: "Automotive update test"
       NAME: "Level crossing"
     type: "Feature"
for (var i in self.feat_att) {

            geomtype = self.feat_att[i].geometry.type;
            switch(geomtype) {
                case "Point":
                    geom = self.feat_att[i].geometry.coordinates;
                    feature =  new ol.geom.Point([geom]);
                    break;
                case "MultiPoint":
                     feature = new ol.geom.MultiPoint([geom]);
                     break;
                case "LineString":
                     feature = new ol.geom.LineString([geom]);
                     break;
                case "MultiLineString":
                     geom = self.feat_att[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
                     feature = new ol.geom.MultiLineString([geom]);
                     break;
                case "Polygon":
                     feature = new ol.geom.Polygon([geom]);
                     break;
                case "MultiPolygon":
                      geom = self.feat_att[i].geometry.coordinates;
                      feature = new ol.geom.MultiPolygon([geom]);
                      break;

            }
            var att_columns = self.feat_att[i].properties
            var featobj = {the_geom:feature}
            var attobj = $.extend(featobj, att_columns)
            var featurething = new ol.Feature(attobj)
            var featid = self.feat_att[i].id

            featurething.setId(featid)
            /*switch (p) {
                case 'update':
                    node =  formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [featurething], null, formatGML);
                    break;
            }*/
            console.log(featurething);
            node =  formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, [featurething], null, formatGML);
            s =  new XMLSerializer();
            str = s.serializeToString(node);
            var feat_data=str.replace("feature:tn_poi",'geowebmap_ws:tn_highways');
            console.log(feat_data);
            $.ajax(base_URL+'geowebmap_ws/ows', {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'text/xml',
                data: feat_data,
                error: function (xhr) {
                   var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                   alert(err.message);
                }
            }).done();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `gml:pos` element, instead of

```
<pos>8682209.29541959,1159929.44262119 undefined</pos>
```

it should be

```
<pos srsDimension="3">8682209.29541959 1159929.44262119 0</pos>
```

or

```
<pos srsDimension="2">8682209.29541959 1159929.44262119</pos>
```

From a quick look at the [OL docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.geom.Point.html) it looks like you need to specify

```
feature =  new ol.geom.Point([geom],'XY');
```

to prevent OL thinking you have a `Z` or `M` element in your array. I think the commas come from mixing GML 2 and GML3 but I can't see where you set up you `formatGML` object, but a WFS 1.1.0 will be expection GML2.

Comment: I am using 
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML2({
                featureNS: base_URL+'web/geowebmap_ws',
                featureType: 'tn_poi',
                srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
And feature =  new ol.geom.Point([geom],'XY');
Still am getting the same error